# Extract coefficient with p from a quantile regression by group with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, quantile, quantreg

I would like to extract p-values and coefficients from a series of quantile regressions made with a grouping variable. I mostly use `dplyr` to manipulate data frames so a would like `dplyr` solution.

```
require(quantreg)
data("engel")
require(dplyr)
engel$grp <- trunc(runif(nrow(engel), min=0, max=3))

group_by(engel,grp) %>% do(summary(rq(foodexp~income,data=.,tau=c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95)),se="boot"))
```

This result in a error

> Error: Results are not data frames at positions: 1, 2, 3

I tried another version doing first the models and later the summary

```
rqm <- group_by(engel,grp) %>% do(mdl=rq(foodexp~income,data=.,tau=c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95)))
summarise(rqm, coef(summary(mdl,se="boot")))
```

which also result in error

> Error: not a vector

Comment: `do` requires a data.frame as an output. You could try `group_by(engel,grp) %>% do(as.data.frame(lapply(summary(rq(foodexp~income,data=.,tau=c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95)),se="boot"), coef)))`

Comment: That works! but insted of having all quantiles (taus) in one row how could I put the results for each tau in a separate row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a mess, but it works:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(engel,grp) %>% 
      do(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
          lapply(summary(rq(foodexp~income,data=.,tau=c(.05, .25, .5, .75, .95)), se="boot"), coef)
            ), row.names = NULL))
```

You would then want to label the rows with the tau values and if it is a coef or p value. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: I have been using R for a year and I have no idea what is going on here. but this helps me get slightly closer to solving my problem.

Comment: @BrandonKuczenski you might have better luck using the `broom` package these days, it's made for running models across dataframes like this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I was actually using `broom::tidy()` and discovered that what I *really* wanted could be accomplished simply by adding the `se = "nid"` switch to my `tidy()` call, cf https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/issues/404

Comment: Really what this did was help me to better understand what the tidyverse tools are doing under the hood